# Difficulty seeing through transparency on images as planes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, image

I'm trying to import images as planes to make a diorama in blender, and with Cycles, the images have this strange artifact where you can't see through some of them: The black part in the image below. Right now i have them all as blend mode: Alpha blend, and shadow mode: alpha hashed. Does anybody know what could be going on?
[image]

Below is what the same setup looks like in Eevee with a reflection plane, was wanting to use cycles to try to make the reflection they're standing on like water and add some ripples and things. Any idea what could be happening? Thank you!!!
[image]

Comment: _Alpha Blend_ and _Alpha Hashed_ are only used for Eevee, those settings don't matter for Cycles. Is the above Cycles screenshot showing the _Rendered View_ or is it _Material Preview_? Because alpha transparency is shown in black in Cycles when you're in _Material Preview_, it's only transparent in _Rendered View_. If this is _Rendered View_ then you maybe have to go to _Render Settings_ > _Light Paths_ > _Max Bounces_ and set a higher value for _Transparency_ (or even for _Transmission_). Then you maybe need to set the _Total_ bounces higher as well.

Comment: You got it! The transparency options in the render settings is what did it. Thank you so much!! Blender is great, but there's so many settings that I have no idea where to even start looking when something goes wrong. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: I've entered this as an answer with even further explanations. Maybe this will help others as well.

Comment: @batFINGER Although that answer has lots of upvotes, the respondent mixes up _Transparency_ and _Transmission_ bounces, especially because he says that from Blender 2.8* upwards you should increase the _Transmission_ bounces. But that's wrong, this wouldn't help in this case. Also he doesn't give hints on the dependencies between _Total_ and _Transmission_ bounces. In his screenshot they both have a value of 12, which is okay. But if 12 wasn't enough, increasing only the _Transmission_ bounces won't make a difference - whereas _Transparency_ (which is what's needed) would work when increased.

Comment: Suggest making this comment on potential dupe answer, so Drudge nka  @Ascalon can also make the required  Transmission --> Transparency edit

Comment: Yes, I did. I hope this not to be closed as duplicate, because it wasn't clear to me if the screenshot was _Material Preview_ or _Rendered View_, and there is a different possible solution for the black area if it was only preview as I say in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha Blend and Alpha Hashed are only used for Eevee, those settings don't matter for Cycles.

In Cycles, *Alpha transparency* is shown different in *Rendered View* and *Material Preview*. *Alpha transparency* (like from an alpha channel or the *Transparent Shader*) is shown in black for Alpha = 0 in Material Preview or not shown as transparent at all when Alpha > 0, it's only transparent in *Rendered View*.

When the transparent parts are shown black in *Rendered View* then you maybe have to go to *Render Settings* > *Light Paths* > *Max Bounces* and set a higher value for *Transparency*, this is for materials with transparency set in the *Alpha channel* of the *Principled BSDF* for example or where the textures have *Alpha maps* to mix in with a *Transparent Shader* or volumes like a *Smoke Domain* etc. The *Transparency Bounces* can be set independently without having to change other bounce values.

If you instead have a *Glass BSDF* or other transmissive material like using the *Transmission channel* in the *Principled BSDF*, then you have to set a higher bounce value for *Transmission* in *Light Paths*, and maybe even in *Total* if it's too low. Because unlike *Transparency*, the *Transmission* (and other) bounces are dependent on the *Total* value. Setting *Transmission* to 16 with a *Total* set to 4 will result in having *Transmission* clipped to 4 as well, so the *Total* value should cover the highest value of the individual bounces (except for *Transparency*).

[image: bounce settings]

PS: I've included the *Smoke Domain* as example for *Transparency* bounces because, apart from having a bounce value for *Volume* here as well, low transparency bounces are what sometimes causes smoke to have ugly black artifacts, which I've seen a lot in smoke tutorials but tutors tend to call it a bug or clipping by the *Adaptive Domain*.

Comment: thank you for all the detail! This is really helpful :)